# Sending form input to controller function

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to let user enter an id, then see the children of that ID (via a self-join association). My children function works in the rails console, but not in the controller, because I suspect I'm sending the form input to the controller wrong.

Controller:

```
    def index
..............
    if params[:children]
      @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])
      @guideline.children
    else
      @guidelines = Guideline.all
    end
  end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <td><%= label_tag(:seeChildren, "See Immediate Children")%></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag :seeChildren, params[:seeChildren], placeholder: "Enter ID" %></td>
  <td><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></td>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    guidelines GET    /guidelines(.:format)          guidelines#index
               POST   /guidelines(.:format)          guidelines#create
 new_guideline GET    /guidelines/new(.:format)      guidelines#new
edit_guideline GET    /guidelines/:id/edit(.:format) guidelines#edit
     guideline GET    /guidelines/:id(.:format)      guidelines#show
               PATCH  /guidelines/:id(.:format)      guidelines#update
               PUT    /guidelines/:id(.:format)      guidelines#update
               DELETE /guidelines/:id(.:format)      guidelines#destroy
          root GET    /                              welcome#index
```

I appreciate the help! I'm sure it's a stupidly simple solution, but I can't seem to find the answer myself

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: in form

**<%= text_field_tag :seeChildren, params[:seeChildren], placeholder: "Enter ID" %>** change this too

'<%= text_field_tag :seeChildren, placeholder: "Enter ID" %>'

in controller

'@guideline = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])' change this line to

'@guideline = Guideline.find(params[:guideline][:seeChildren])'

Comment: I get a "NoMethodError in Guidelines#index" when it tries to render index with the children params

Comment: is guidelines scaffold

Comment: no it isn't. I defined all the methods

Comment: can you show me your routes

Comment: added it to my question

Comment: When you submit a form, you are sending a post request.  Based on the route info, where does a post request to guidelines_path go?  It's not the index action.

Comment: Also, when you post files, do NOT say 'controller' or 'form'.  You need to post the EXACT name of the file with a couple of paths in front of it, e.g. `views/some_controller/index.html.erb`.  You also need to post COMPLETE error messages showing file names and line numbers where the error occurred, and the code mentioned in the error. Your whole post is very, very sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect I'm sending the form input to the controller wrong.

```
text_field_tag :seeChildren, params[:seeChildren], placeholder: "Enter ID" %>
```

Do this instead:

```
text_field_tag :seeChildren, nil, placeholder: "Enter ID" %>
```

which will create this html:

```
<input id="seeChildren" type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" name="seeChildren">
```

When the user submits the form, one of the name/value pairs sent to the server will be `seeChildren="some text"`, where `seeChildren` is the name attribute of the textfield, and "some text" is whatever the user entered.

`params[:seeChildren]` won't exist until *after* the user submits the form.   When the browser sends the request created by the form to the server, rails extracts all the name/value pairs into the params Hash.

Comment: What about in the controller? because that still gives me the no method error

Comment: @JohnDodson, You said your *children function*, whatever that is, works fine in the rails console.  What you do with the information from the form is up to you.  It matters not whether you write: `@guideline = Guideline.find("something")` or `@guideline = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])` when the user enters "something" in the text field.

Comment: could I be getting the error because the id is an integer and the params of seeChildren is a string?

Comment: @JohnDodson where you are setting `params[:children]` parameter as you have written condition using that variable

Comment: @JohnDodson, **could I be getting the error because the id is an integer and the params of seeChildren is a string?** Open up a rails console and find out for yourself.